# Proof of KAM Theorem

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics, hamilton-equations, hamilton-jacobi-equation

I've been looking for some well-written proof on the KAM Theorem that has all the details and ideas (and if it's not to much that is in some sense elementary).

Does anyone happen to know any good and complete reference?

Comment: I imagine the last chapter on perturbation theory in Arnold's *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics* is an excellent place to pick up the techniques "in action", as well as his Appendix 8 on Kolmogorov's Theorem. It's perhaps not a "self contained" guide to modern KAM theory, but Arnold has this stupefying way of using the simplest machinery to lay the theory bare, and the good news is it also serves as a reference to objects you don't know.

Answer (score 4):

I must admit, I have not studied it in detail, but I would suggest the following outline by Pöschel

http://www.poschel.de/pbl/kam-1.pdf

He is usually very clear and detailed. In case you did not have the classical KAM theorem in mind, Pöschel has also a book together with Kappeler called "KdV & KAM" where they show a KAM theorem for the KdV equation.

In case you like to read some stories and history on KAM, I recommend you to read "The KAM story. A friendly introduction to content, significance and history of Kolmogorov-Arnold-Moser theory" by Dumas.